# Gerund as a PP complement

Tags: syntax, gerund

What would be the structure for a phrase like, 'before speaking to him' ? Will 'before' take a  CP as the complement and treat 'speaking' like a PRO-ing or is it something else? 
Somebody please help me with the structure for this.

Comment: which class is this for?

Comment: Use it in a complete grammatical sentence; _before speaking to him_ could possibly have several structures.